# Copy-Item : Could not find part of the path DirectoryNotFoundException Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy folders and files from one location to another location on the same server.  I have found some script that does the job, but only if I run it twice.  The first time I run the script, I get an error:

```
Copy-Item : Could not find part of the path 'C:\***\***\***\***.dll
Copy-Item -Destination {
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

When I run the code a second time, all the subsequent folders and files get copied.

Here is the code:

```
$From = "C:\b\125\Build\396\src\Integration"
$to = "C:\Build\396\396_20151203.5\Integration\"

$exclude = @("*.cs", "*.csproj*")
$excludeMatch = @("Configurations")

#Copy-Item $source $to -Recurse

    Get-ChildItem -Path $From -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
        Where-Object {
            $excludeMatch -eq $null -or `
            $_.FullName.Replace($From, "") -notmatch $excludeMatch
        } | Copy-Item -Destination {
            if($_.PSIsContainer) {
                Join-Path $to $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($From.Length)
            } else {
                Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($From.Length)
            }
        } -Force -Exclude $exclude
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems a bit too convoluted.

Why not try this?

```
$from = "C:\b\125\Build\396\src\Integration"
$to = "C:\Build\396\396_20151203.5\Integration\"

$exclude = @("*.cs", "*.csproj*", "Configurations")

Get-ChildItem $from -Exclude $exclude -Recurse -Force |
    Copy-Item -Destination {
        Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.Length)
    }
```

Comment: the exclusions are not being applied.  I have to make sure the *.cs files are not copied at the least.

Comment: You are right, I have modified my answer, can you please test again ?

Comment: Sorry for my absence. This solution errors out at the web.config.dev in the configurations folder. Adding the following under the variable declaration is working:</br>
    If (Test-Path -Path $to -PathType Container) </br>
    { Write-Host "$to already exists" -ForegroundColor Red} </br>
    ELSE { New-Item -Path $to -ItemType directory }

Comment: So you found a way to make it work ? If you're OK with it, you can accept the answer.

Comment: A, if you (JCollier) figured out something that works, please edit/APPEND your original post saying "This works using sodawillows input and a few tweaks",... then also mark sodawillows answer the the answer (since it got you to the answer).   1.  This will provide future readers (like me) the working code that isn't just in a comment that is hard to see/format and 2.  It will stop having this question show up as "unanswered" on the SOF's queries.  Thanks for your consideration.